# Visual studio code - Python debug gives "No module named...." error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Ik have created a python test file in VSC. When I run this file it works fine and I see my output in the browser (Dash/Flask). However when I try to debug the file in VSC it gives me an error "No module named test.py" For sure I select the Python debug option.

My file structure is:

```
-root
 -chapter
  -test.py
```

What is the difference in debug and not debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some options. In the end this worked for me: "cwd": "${fileDirname}",

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `launch.json`. I have attached mine as a simple reference.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true,
    }
]
```

By the way, you can debug here

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same. But still the issue

Comment: I tried some options. In the end this worked for me: "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
Thanks @Minglie-MSFT